# Best practice to keep tables updated in oracle

Tags: oracle, procedure, jsf-1.2

i have an application in jsf 1.2. Oracle 11g is on the BE. Now i have made some complex summaries from some tables that i display on the FE application. Approach i have used is to write procedures in oracle, they would populate the summary table every 5 minutes using DBMS_SCHEDULAR, and then simply display those tables using JSF rich data table control. I am not invoking the procedures from the FE since it produces a lag and user thinks that application has hanged. This approach is working but there still is a delay of 5 minutes. So, what should be the best approach in such a case? i cannot use views since i have to make complex calculations inside oracle procedures to populate the summary tables which is not possible (atleast for me) to do with the help of views or mat_views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the lag, you'd need to use materialized views.  You'd want to use materialized views even if you just wanted the materialized views to refresh every 5 minutes rather than writing your own code.  You say that you can't use materialized views but you don't really explain why that is which makes it impossible to offer any specific help.

Comment: sir the fact that i am not using mat views is attributed to complex nature of final summaries i am / can generate via PL/SQL procedures. I am calculating values from multiple tables, running loops , if else statements etc which is not possible writing stereotype sql for a view.

Comment: Then it's going to be impossible to offer you much assistance.  If you want to avoid the lag, you'd want fast refreshable materialized views.    If you're saying that this is impossible, then eliminating the lag is impossible.  It seems unlikely to me that you really have logic for building summaries that is so complex that it cannot be reasonably expressed in SQL.  But if you don't want to consider that avenue, then you're closing off the most logical way to resolve your problem.

Comment: ok so i got my answer. the best practice should be mat views right? which i cant / want to do may coz i am not good enough in my sql abilities that i should work on for future work. thanks.